# WPF control alignment is wrong when dynamically added

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Hi I thought I could solve this easily but it is driving me crazy.

I am using a UserControl to house a video player control based on VLC, along with play and stop buttons etc. I then place the UserControl on my main form. if the UserControl is declared in XAML it behaves normally.

I decided to rewrite the code to instantiate my UserControl dynamically, in case I need to destroy it and create another on the fly. But when I do the video moves to the top of its container instead of the middle.

[image]

The UserControl relevant section is here:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutParent" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="12" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- I comment this if adding player dynamically -->
        <!--<wpf:VlcPlayer Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Player" />-->

        <!-- I un-comment this if adding player dynamically -->
        <Grid x:Name="VideoPlayerPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Opacity="0.8">
            ...(buttons etc)
        </StackPanel>

        <ProgressBar ...(progressBar etc) />
</Grid>
```

My codebehind looks like this:

```
Dim Player As VlcPlayer = New VlcPlayer ' uncomment If adding the player dynamically

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Player.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, -1)
        VideoPlayerPanel.Children.Add(Player)

        VolumeSlider.Value = 50
    End Sub
```

I have tried `VerticalAlignment="Center"` and  `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` in XAML on the VideoPlayerPanel, with Center the video disappears entirely, with Stretch it still aligns to the top.

Any thoughts as to what I might do to align this centrally would be much appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that you placed your VLC UI on a Canvas, and that's a control whose dimensions must be explicitly declared. Thus, when you place the control inside a Grid, for instance, the framework is not able to compute the correct arrangement. Remember that a Canvas always sizes as zero, unless you declare width and height.

Comment: Creating XAML stuff in code behind is often not a great idea. There isn't a lot that's not best done with templates. The more time I spend with XAML, the more I see stuff like this and think "why would I do that to myself?" Was there some specific issue you ran into doing this conventionally?

Answer (score 1):

When adding Player dynamiccaly you have different result, because you wrap Play in additional Grid. Try to add Player directly to first row of LayoutParent:

```
Player.SetValue(Grid.Row, 0)
LayoutParent.Children.Add(Player)
```

Comment: I had previously tried LayoutParent as well, same result. I tried Player.SetValue(Grid.Row,0) but that doesnt compile, I think since Grid.Row is an attached property. Grid.RowProperty is valid but again no difference.

Comment: Can you show XAML for your UserConrol? I cannot reproduce this issue with simple UserControl, containing fixed height Grid with background

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all that replied.

I did some more research, I substituted in a Rectangle for the player control and it aligned perfectly. That led me to discover that the third party control was itself at fault. I had to get the source and change the VerticalAlignment directly.

Sorry for the runaround.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Height="*"` from first `Row` . `*` is used to occupy remaining space, so it is good to use it for the last `Row`.

Use fixed width and or `Auto`.

Comment: In this case I want the video to fit itself into the remaining space left after the following rows have been filled, even though that space occupies the first row in the grid, so * is what I want.